# how to change mocked function behaviour?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a function I want to mock:

```
class Base{
public:
void virtual func() { sleep(3); }
};
```

My mock would look like:

```
class Mock: public Base{
public:
MOCK_METHOD(void, func, (), (override));
};
```

And the test would look like:

```
TEST(TestMockSanity, AbleToMock) {                                                       
Mock mock;                                                                    
EXPECT_CALL(mock, func());   
}
```

however, I have 2 issues:

1. **something silly** - error: ‘class testing::internal::TypedExpectation<void()>’ has no member named ‘TIMES’
2. **Important** - How do I change the implemntation of `func` to `sleep(0)`?

---

./real.hpp

```
class Real {
 public:
  Real(){};
  virtual ~Real(){};
  virtual int run();
  virtual int dont_run();
};
```

./real.cpp

```
#include "real.hpp"

int Real::run() { return 0; };
int Real::dont_run() { return 1; };
```

./meson.build

```
project(
  'gtest',
  'cpp',
  default_options : [
    'cpp_std=c++14',
  ],
)

sources = files('main.cpp', 'real.cpp')

executable(
  'real',
  sources,
  install : false,
)

executable(
  'mock',
  files('real.cpp', 'mock.cpp'),
  dependencies: [dependency('gtest'), dependency('gmock')],
  install : false,
)
```

./mock.cpp

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"  // MOCK_METHOD
#include "gtest/gtest.h"  // TEST
#include "real.hpp"

class MockReal : public Real {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, run, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, dont_run, (), (override));

  void delegate(){
      ON_CALL(*this, run).WillByDefault([this](){
          return 1;
      });
      ON_CALL(*this, dont_run).WillByDefault([this](){
          return 2;
      });
  }
};

TEST(TestMockSanity, AbleToMock) {
  MockReal mock;

  EXPECT_EQ(0, mock.run());
  EXPECT_EQ(1, mock.dont_run());

  mock.delegate();

  EXPECT_EQ(1, mock.run());
  EXPECT_EQ(2, mock.dont_run());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

./main.cpp

```
#include "real.hpp"

int main() {
  Real r;
  r.run();
  return 0;
}
```

subprojects/gtest.wrap

```
[wrap-file]
directory = googletest-release-1.11.0
source_url = https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.11.0.tar.gz
source_filename = gtest-1.11.0.tar.gz
source_hash = b4870bf121ff7795ba20d20bcdd8627b8e088f2d1dab299a031c1034eddc93d5
patch_filename = gtest_1.11.0-2_patch.zip
patch_url = https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v2/gtest_1.11.0-2/get_patch
patch_hash = 764530d812ac161c9eab02a8cfaec67c871fcfc5548e29fd3d488070913d4e94

[provide]
gtest = gtest_dep
gtest_main = gtest_main_dep
gmock = gmock_dep
gmock_main = gmock_main_dep
```

And I get after running:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from TestMockSanity
[ RUN      ] TestMockSanity.AbleToMock

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: run()
          Returns: 0
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: dont_run()
          Returns: 0
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
../mock.cpp:24: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  1
  mock.dont_run()
    Which is: 0

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
../mock.cpp:11:
    Function call: run()
          Returns: 1
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
../mock.cpp:14:
    Function call: dont_run()
          Returns: 2
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect for details.
[  FAILED  ] TestMockSanity.AbleToMock (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from TestMockSanity (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] TestMockSanity.AbleToMock

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Comment: Have a look at [ON_CALL](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html) in the documentation

Comment: Looks good, but I'm unable to make it work - I'm posting my entire project in the question. I'm getting all kinds of unexpected behaviours on this... - also posted in the question body - it seems gmock overrides my ON_CALL and returns 0 even though I asked to return 1 or 2

Comment: `error: ‘class testing::internal::TypedExpectation<void()>’ has no member named ‘TIMES’` - [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ME6hcofv5).

Comment: It might be only for gtest 1.11.2. I need to check it on the latest version, but as I'm working with meson, it's kinda hard

Answer (score 1):

When you mock function members, you say that you will expect their calls. Since you have not added `EXPECT_CALL` rules, `MockReal` informs you about uninterested mocked calls. You might want to explicitly state that you allow uninterested calls:

```
::testing::NiceMock<MockReal> mock;
```

When you mock function members

```
class MockReal : public Real {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, run, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, dont_run, (), (override));
};
```

they are just override the base class members:

```
class MockReal : public Real {
 public:
  int run() override {
    return int{};  // Actually, some expression that evaluates to the default value int{}.
  }
  int dont_run() override {
    return int{};  // Actually, some another expression that also evaluates to 0.
  }
};
```

It's a usual virtual method call - they don't call parent methods. If you want them to call the parent methods, you usually call them explicitly:

```
  int run() override {
    return Real::run();
  }
```

You can control the default return expressions with `ON_CALL().WillByDefault()`, they should be set in the constructor or anywhere before method calls, similarly above:

```
  MockReal() {
    ON_CALL(*this, run).WillByDefault([this] { return Real::run(); });
    ON_CALL(*this, dont_run).WillByDefault([this] { return Real::dont_run(); });
  }
```

The whole code:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Real {
 public:
  Real(){};
  virtual ~Real() = default;
  virtual int run();
  virtual int dont_run();
};

int Real::run() { return 0; };
int Real::dont_run() { return 1; };

class MockReal : public Real {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, run, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(int, dont_run, (), (override));

  MockReal() {
    // Set default actions.
    ON_CALL(*this, run).WillByDefault([this] { return Real::run(); });
    ON_CALL(*this, dont_run).WillByDefault([this] { return Real::dont_run(); });
  }
  
  void delegate(){
    // Override default actions.
    ON_CALL(*this, run).WillByDefault(::testing::Return(1));
    ON_CALL(*this, dont_run).WillByDefault(::testing::Return(2));
  }
};

TEST(TestMockSanity, AbleToMock) {
  ::testing::NiceMock<MockReal> mock;

  EXPECT_EQ(0, mock.run());
  EXPECT_EQ(1, mock.dont_run());

  mock.delegate();

  EXPECT_EQ(1, mock.run());
  EXPECT_EQ(2, mock.dont_run());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Output

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from TestMockSanity
[ RUN      ] TestMockSanity.AbleToMock
[       OK ] TestMockSanity.AbleToMock (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from TestMockSanity (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got something like this in my ServerMock class
that also has MOCK_METHODs

```
ServerMock()
{
    ON_CALL(*this, Stop).WillByDefault([this] { StopImpl(); });
}

void StopImpl() const
{
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: it is similar to what I've done. It seems to kinda work - but I still don't get the issue with "unintersting calls" which breaks some of my tests as it seems

Answer (score -1):

**Issue 1:** You have to say how often you expect the call of `func()` in `EXPECT_CALL`. For example like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, func()).Times(1);
```

**Issue 2:** You can use Googletests [`Invoke`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/actions.html) to do an action on the call.

Comment: *You have to say how often you expect the call* - false. `.Times(1)` is a default number of calls.